# Mybatis doesn't Roll Back Sequences

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jdbc, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I have a problem creating test using Spring Boot + My Batis Spring Boot
I have created a couple of U. Test for my mappers. For the insertions, I use the `@SelectKey` annotation to get the next value of the sequence. When Spring rolls back the transaction doesn't roll back the sequence and it increment it in each application start.

FE.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "local")
@SpringBootTest
@Slf4j
@Transactional
public class MultimediaMapperTest {

    @Autowired
    private MultimediaMapper multimediaMapper;

    @Autowired
    private IEmpresasService empresasService;



    @Test
    public void insertArchivo() {
        Multimedia archivo = Multimedia.builder()
                .tiposEntidad(TiposEntidad.EMP)
                .idEntidad(1)
                .awsKey("KEY_AMAZON_WEB_SERVICES")
                .nomFichero("fichero.txt")
                .mime("application/pdf")
                .observaciones("prueba observaciones")
                .build();

        multimediaMapper.insertArchivos(archivo);
        log.debug("Fin de la inserción de {}", archivo);
        assertThat(archivo.getIdArchivo(), is(notNullValue()));

    }
```

Log:

First start:

```
[INFO ] 2018-04-23 21:44:16,369 [] o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Starting beans in phase 2147483647
[INFO ] 2018-04-23 21:44:16,369 [] s.d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper - Context refreshed
[INFO ] 2018-04-23 21:44:16,396 [] s.d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper - Found 1 custom documentation plugin(s)
[INFO ] 2018-04-23 21:44:16,470 [] s.d.s.w.s.ApiListingReferenceScanner - Scanning for api listing references
[INFO ] 2018-04-23 21:44:16,880 [] e.g.m.a.d.MultimediaMapperTest - Started MultimediaMapperTest in 7.035 seconds (JVM running for 8.255)
[INFO ] 2018-04-23 21:44:18,600 [] o.s.t.c.t.TransactionContext - Began transaction (1) for test context [DefaultTestContext@40d10264 testClass = MultimediaMapperTest, testInstance = es.gogroup.module.archivos.dao.MultimediaMapperTest@6edd4fe2, testMethod = insertArchivo@MultimediaMapperTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@2773504f testClass = MultimediaMapperTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class es.gogroup.PanchoApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{local}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextCustomizer@2a798d51, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@37afeb11, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@245b4bdc, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@1b7cc17c], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]]]; transaction manager [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager@cfb94fd]; rollback [true]
[DEBUG] 2018-04-23 21:44:18,662 [] e.g.m.m.d.M.insertArchivos!selectKey - ==>  Preparing: SELECT pg_catalog.nextval('"SEQ_MULTIMEDIA"'); 
[DEBUG] 2018-04-23 21:44:18,689 [] e.g.m.m.d.M.insertArchivos!selectKey - ==> Parameters: 
[DEBUG] 2018-04-23 21:44:18,759 [] e.g.m.m.d.M.insertArchivos!selectKey -   Preparing: INSERT INTO MULTIMEDIA(ID_ARCHIVO,TIPO_ENTIDAD, ID_ENTIDAD,AWS_KEY, NOM_FICHERO, OBSERVACIONES, MIME) VALUES (?,?,?,?, ?, ?, ?) 
[DEBUG] 2018-04-23 21:44:18,767 [] e.g.m.m.d.M.insertArchivos - ==> Parameters: 15(Integer), EMP(String), 1(Integer), KEY_AMAZON_WEB_SERVICES(String), fichero.txt(String), prueba observaciones(String), application/pdf(String)
[DEBUG] 2018-04-23 21:44:18,803 [] e.g.m.m.d.M.insertArchivos -
```

Next start:

```
[INFO ] 2018-04-23 21:58:15,778 [] o.s.t.c.t.TransactionContext - Began transaction (1) for test context [DefaultTestContext@40d10264 testClass = MultimediaMapperTest, testInstance = es.gogroup.module.archivos.dao.MultimediaMapperTest@6edd4fe2, testMethod = insertArchivo@MultimediaMapperTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@2773504f testClass = MultimediaMapperTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class es.gogroup.PanchoApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{local}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextCustomizer@2a798d51, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@37afeb11, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@245b4bdc, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@1b7cc17c], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]]]; transaction manager [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager@cfb94fd]; rollback [true]
[DEBUG] 2018-04-23 21:58:15,856 [] e.g.m.m.d.M.insertArchivos!selectKey - ==>  Preparing: SELECT pg_catalog.nextval('"SEQ_MULTIMEDIA"'); 
[DEBUG] 2018-04-23 21:58:15,888 [] e.g.m.m.d.M.insertArchivos!selectKey - ==> Parameters: 
[DEBUG] 2018-04-23 21:58:15,954 [] e.g.m.m.d.M.insertArchivos!selectKey -   Preparing: INSERT INTO MULTIMEDIA(ID_ARCHIVO,TIPO_ENTIDAD, ID_ENTIDAD,AWS_KEY, NOM_FICHERO, OBSERVACIONES, MIME) VALUES (?,?,?,?, ?, ?, ?) 
[DEBUG] 2018-04-23 21:58:15,964 [] e.g.m.m.d.M.insertArchivos - ==> Parameters: 16(Integer), EMP(String), 1(Integer), KEY_AMAZON_WEB_SERVICES(String), fichero.txt(String), prueba observaciones(String), application/pdf(String)
[DEBUG] 2018-04-23 21:58:16,001 [] e.g.m.m.d.M.insertArchivos -
```

Comment: Have you tried to simulate this scenario using your favorite SQL client?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Database sequences cannot be rolled back. That's a feature, not a bug. :)

[PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-sequence.html):

> Important: To avoid blocking concurrent transactions that obtain
>   numbers from the same sequence, a nextval operation is never rolled
>   back; that is, once a value has been fetched it is considered used,
>   even if the transaction that did the nextval later aborts. This means
>   that aborted transactions might leave unused "holes" in the sequence
>   of assigned values.

[Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/views002.htm#ADMIN11792):

> Once a sequence number is generated, the sequence number is available
>   only to the session that generated the number. Independent of
>   transactions committing or rolling back, other users referencing
>   order_seq.NEXTVAL obtain unique values. If two users are accessing the
>   same sequence concurrently, then the sequence numbers each user
>   receives might have gaps because sequence numbers are also being
>   generated by the other user.

[SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ff878091(v=sql.110).aspx):

> Sequence numbers are generated outside the scope of the current
>   transaction. They are consumed whether the transaction using the
>   sequence number is committed or rolled back.